# How much Program Memory does PIC24FJ1024GB610 have?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, flash-memories

PIC24FJ1024 got 1024KBytes of Program Memory.

In the PIC24's Data Sheet in Chapter 4, mentions that the Program memory runs from 0x000000 to 0x7FFFFF which is 8,388 KByte.

[image]

Can someone explain why this duality?

Comment: marketing, they probably counted some of the bits in the config space.

Comment: The table in your question tells you 'Unimplimented Read 0'. There's nothing at those addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse "memory space" (which is just the amount of all valid addresses, whether they are actually connected to program memory, RAM or some peripheral), and actual memory.

So, here, the memory space might be 8 MB, but, as the footnote says,

> exact boundary sizes are determined by the size of the implemented program memory.

So, some addresses in that space actually point to hardware memory, and others simply point to nowhere.

Comment: so there is 8MB of memory space, but we can only use 1MB, is that correct?
Also how come the Program Memory points to RAM, doesn't PIC24 have a Harvard Arch. where Program and Data are seperate. (I am new to Microcontrollers)

Comment: There's no RAM mentioned anywhere there... That is the program side only.

Comment: I know, I just got confused by @MarcusMuller  comment, that some of the Program Memory Space points to RAM i.e it is a pointer to Data RAM

Comment: sorry for the misleading wording. Corrected.